# conda create --name doc-env python==3.7 but the version given with python -V is 3.11

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda, virtualenv

I try to install python 3.7 with conda but every time I seem to get python 3.11. Then I tried to explicitly specify the channel with `conda create --name doc-env python=3.7 -c conda-forge` I noticed that I don't see the environment in the left parenthesis. How can I install my version of python in my environment? Other than Anaconda, I don't have Python on my machine.

```
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\document-qa-webui> conda create --name doc-env python==3.7        
WARNING: A conda environment already exists at 'C:\Users\antoi\anaconda3\envs\doc-env'
Remove existing environment (y/[n])? Y

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.7.4
  latest version: 23.9.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=23.9.0



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\antoi\anaconda3\envs\doc-env

  added / updated specs:
    - python==3.7


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-3.7.0               |       hea74fb7_0        16.6 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        16.6 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  certifi            pkgs/main/win-64::certifi-2022.12.7-py37haa95532_0
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-22.3.1-py37haa95532_0
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.7.0-hea74fb7_0
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-65.6.3-py37haa95532_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.2-h21ff451_1
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016-h5e58377_2
  wheel              pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.38.4-py37haa95532_0
  wincertstore       pkgs/main/win-64::wincertstore-0.2-py37haa95532_2


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate doc-env
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\document-qa-webui> conda activate doc-env
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\document-qa-webui> python -V
Python 3.11.5
```

Comment: What do you get when running `which python` from the conda environment?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Learningisamess I get `/c/Users/antoi/anaconda3/python`

Comment: yeah it does not seem to point to the right one, which should be `/c/Users/antoi/anaconda3/envs/doc-env/bin/python`. I suspect your terminal cannot load the environment. I don't know enough about Windows terminals to advise a solution unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for your comment anyway @Learningisamess I guess you're right. Should I ask it on SuperUser?